# Порядок выполнения в файле htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Имеем такой файл htaccess

```
Options -Indexes 
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Redirect 301 /old_adress /new_address_/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/[^/\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/{2,}(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

сверху стоит редирект со старой страницы на совершенно другую, при этом у старой на конце не было слеша.

Ниже есть конструкция, которая добавляет слеш во все адреса, где его нет

И в итоге мы получаем что переходя по старой ссылке человека кидает на страницу
/new_address_//

Для удаления этих слешей добавлена последняя запись

Вопрос в том, что почему вторая запись редиректа с добавлением слеша выполняется раньше редиректа со старой страницы.

Т.е. сначала идет редирект с /old_adress на /old_adress/
Потом по правилу /old_adress заменяет на /new_address_/ и т.к. у нас уже появился слеш на конце то в конце уже 2 слеша

Comment: с конкатинацией всё нормально?

Comment: не совсем понял о чем речь